# TableView Inside tableView's Cell, Dynamic Height

Tags: ios, nested, tableview, uitableview, row-height

I am new to IOS and for some reasons I have to use tableview inside a tableview's Cell. I have achieved this successfully. But thing is my cells are of dynamic height and to calculate height I am using apple's new method .

```
  self.replyTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
  self.replyTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0;
```

for calculation of height. These are the lines that caused trouble, as soon as I add these lines of code inner tableview disappear, nothing shows there not even white space, it seems like by adding these lines inner table's height becomes zero.
Please any suggestion will be great if anyone have experienced of it. Thanks in advance.

> Note: Both inner and outer tables have dynamic content.(Variable in
>   height)

Comment: Add some more relevant code.

Comment: How about your outer table view rowHeight ?? Did you set **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** for it also ??

Comment: yes I have set for Outer table as well. @gEeKyMiNd

Comment: relevant code ? @dahiya_boy please tell me which part confuse you I will paste code

Comment: You need to ensure you have appropriate vertical constraints in your cells in order for auto layout to determine the cell height

Comment: @Paulw11 how should I apply constraints on Inner Table view ??? right now I have drop 4 constraints ... Top, Bottom, Right, Left. I think this is the main cause of conflict ? any suggestion ?

Comment: What is your content?  How is the content size changing?

Comment: @Paulw11 there are multiple labels with dynamic content.Each time content  length will be different.

Comment: @Najam : Any solution?

Comment: @DaxeshNagar the only solution I found was a simple logic. I used two different cells and depending upon object I have to show provide data from specific list into appropriate cell.

Comment: Hi, have the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @AlexeyChekanov nope ... not yet... I just tackled this problem in an alternate way.... Let's assume you have one array of comments (of course with dynamic height) and each comment can hold an array of replies (again with dynamic height) .. So what I actually did, I created one single generic array by merging comments and replies and in each generic index I put extra variables indicating weather it is comment or reply? And depending upon that value I deque prototype cell.